# Getting refresh_token with lepture/authlib

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, authlib

I'm using Authlib, and attempting to get a refresh_token from a Hydra server. I have the following code:

```
from authlib.client import OAuth2Session

client_id = "my-client"
client_secret = "client secret"
token_url = "https://myhydraserver/token"
scope = 'openid email profile offline'
session = OAuth2Session(client_id, client_secret, scope=scope)

token = session.fetch_access_token(token_url)
print(token)
```

This prints out

```
{'access_token': 'the-token', 'expires_in': 3599, 'scope': '', 'token_type': 'bearer', 'expires_at': 1519224804}
```

From the docs, I see that there's a function to get an access token from a refresh_token, but can't find a way to get a refresh_token in the first place. How would I go about getting a refresh_token? Hydra's configured with:

```
  --grant-types authorization_code,refresh_token,client_credentials,implicit 
  --response-types token,code,id_token
```

which should hand out refresh_tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client_credentials` won't issue refresh token. You need to use authorization_code flow to get the refresh token.

https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/oauth2.html#oauth2session-for-authorization-code

Comment: I actually tried the Authorization_code flow as mentioned with the link but I still receive only an access token (i.e. no refresh token). Is there something I need to set on the server side perhaps?

Comment: @fturkmen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305430/obtaining-refresh-token-from-lepture-authlib-through-authorization-code/51305975#51305975